# Android ListView Data Virtualization - Lazy Loading more than 10,000 items

Tags: android, listview, lazy-loading, ui-virtualization

Does anybody have an example of lazy loading (about 10,000 items) an Android ListView from a Sqlite databse?

Comment: I am sure that you can come up with a better UI that does not involve users having to sift through thousands upon thousands of rows in a list.

Answer (score 2):

Romain Guy's [Shelves](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/) application has been referenced a lot in discussions I've seen on lazy loading. Not sure if it will help you out, but it might be a place to start looking. References to a couple other examples [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d4ba513a5fa90029)